# Наложить пару эфектов на Spinner

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать Spinner как на картинке...

На данный момент нарисовал спиннер с "скругленными краями", добавил стрелку, но не могу добавить желтый элемент, так как не получается задать ему ограниченный размер, либо все желтое либо белое.

Поставить его фоном не могу потому что размер Spinner"а разный на разных екранах.

Не пойму как наложить два item в drawable и нагуглить не получается. Помогите подсказками.

Comment: Спиннер практически не кастомизируем. Проще сделать всё руками и не использовать его вовсе.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо, буду "колдовать"

Как закрыть вопрос правильно в такой ситуации ?

Comment: В идеальном случае на вопрос пишется ответ. Типа "вот так я в итоге сделал и всё работает". Если ответить не хотите - можете просто удалить вопрос.

Comment: Понял, как изменится ситуация отпишусь чем все закончилось, еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создал необходимые ImageView, сделал спиннер прозрачным и подложил под него фон с ImageView